# Correct way of using @Aggregator annotation with MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor

Tags: spring-integration

When creating a `MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor(Object target)` is it correct to annotate the desired processing method in `target` with `@Aggregator` or will this cause a useless creation of an AggregatingMessageHandler object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. That's the logic of that `MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor` and its `MessagingMethodInvokerHelper` delegate:

```
public MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor(Object target) {
    this.processor = new MethodInvokingMessageListProcessor<Object>(target, Aggregator.class);
}
```

Although adding an annotation is still optional, it would be good to have to give that `MessagingMethodInvokerHelper` a little help.

No, it does not create an extra `AggregatingMessageHandler`, if your `@Aggregator` doesn't come with an `inputChannel` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Is the logic not to create the handler unless inputChannel is specified in MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor?

Comment: Yes, see `MethodAnnotationPostProcessor.shouldCreateEndpoint()` for that logic and how it is used.